# Replace all but first and last quotation marks in string

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I need to leave the opening and closing quotation marks alone, but replace any and all other quotation marks within the string. This replaces all:

```
$message = str_replace("\"", "'", $message);
```

How could I modify it to leave the first and last alone?

Comment: Find the indexes of the first and last quotes, pull the substring in between and perform all the replacements there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply remove all quotes then add one at the begining and at the end:

```
$str = '"This "string" contains" double "quotes""';
$str = '"' . str_replace('"', '', $str) . '"';
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
"This string contains double quotes"
```

Answer (score 0):

see following Example,

```
$str= "/123456/";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo str_replace(substr($str,1,-1),"123",$str);
```